# Ajax call don't work - allow cross origin domain don't work with axios ?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, vue.js, http-headers, axios

We use axios to make ajax call with promise. We have the error :

Failed to load xxx : Redirect from xxx to yyyy has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin xxxx is therefore not allowed access.

Our xxxx domain is a vue Js application and YYYY a basic codeginiter V3 framework.

We have had to main controller :  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: xxx');

But that don't seem to work it !

We have try all we can about headers... use  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *), utilise $this->output->set_header of codeigniter, put header in index.php, make Ajax without Axios only XMLHttpRequest, nothing work !

We finally use a trick to call our external url :

```
var script = document.createElement('script');

script.src = yyyy;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
```

But this is not the cleanest way to do..

I want to know if everyone have face the seem issue and how he manage to resolve that.

Thanks for all !

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Maybe about web server setting. Like .htaccess: 
Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"?

Comment: Thank for your participation, but it seem that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Re :

We find the probleme. Codeigniter logique don't work if there is redirection. If you want to make it work, you have to make the most simple controller possible.

Other mistake we have call this url : http://xxxx/disconnect/ instead of http://yyyy/disconnect ( no end-slash )

Other to pay attention, navigator same to save the cache of call. If you want to view your modification clean the cache.

Have good days :) !

Kevin